# QGIS Freehand editing plug-in: blocked attribute table

Tags: qgis, editing, table, digitizing

I can't save object after drawing by Freehand editing plug-in. I suppose it will be connected with creating some (special) column in the table.

[image]

Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: You don't need any specific column aslong as there's atleast one. Do you receive an error message? When you say "blocked", do you mean you can't enter anything as an attribute?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: Version 2.4 Chugiag, of course.

Comment: Yes - I can't enter anything. If I add extra column (text or number) nothing is changing. Also there is no error on main screen whether in python console.

Comment: Did anyone has got similar problem? :(

Comment: Yes I had a similar problem on qgis 2.4.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I am having this same issue with Q2.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being able to save the geometry due to a read only attribute windows with a disabled ok button is an issue in QGIS 2.4. The freehand plugin works fine in QGIS 2.6.0 and QGIS 2.8.1.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't try it in QGIS 2.6, but in 2.8.1 (as you mentioned) works well :)

Comment: You have the option to accept the answer. This may help others in the future with the same problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

Try ticking the checkbox on for

Settings -> Option -> Digitizing -> "Suppress Attribute Form Popup after feature creation."

Comment: I can confirm that this workaround works in QGIS 2.4. Only downside, you have to enter the attribute values after the geometry and null data attributes has been added to the map.